# dot product of subarrays without for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dot-product

when we have:

```
array 1: A, shape (49998,3,3) 
array 2: B, shape (3, 49998)
```

and i want to multiply their subarrays to get

```
array 3: C, shape(3,49998)
```

for which im using generator:

```
def genC(A,B):
    for a,b in itertools.izip(A,B.T):
        c=np.dot(a,b)
        yield c.T[0]

C=np.array([c for c in genC()]).T
```

so how could i do array multiplication insides of A,B without for loop to get array C?

i was trying to use `np.tensordot`, but i cant get it

**NOTE:**

this is just basic example, for some test cos in orginal data i had

4*3*37 arrays A(500 000,3,3) B(3,500 000)

to do, and for loop sems for me not pythonic way xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am getting your code right, you want to perform 49998 dot products of a 3x3 matrix with a 3 vector, right? That is very easy to do with [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
np.einsum('ijk,ki->ij', A, B)
```

Comment: works great, fast and efficient! it seems so i should check out that einsum and similar funcs, so maybe i will kill more for loops xD